# 401 status code error when making service to service call using spring authorization server and feign

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-cloud-feign, spring-authorization-server

I am using spring authorization server with feign for my microservices. Service A has an endpoint that exposes an unprotected resource, but this resource makes a Http call to Service B (protected resource) using feign so there's no user token to be passed to Service B. What approach should I take when system is trying to perform service to service calls, should I use client credentials grant type?

I tried using `spring.cloud.openfeign.oauth2.enabled=true` from docs but it doesn't work. I still get 401 status code.